# Do Mann-Kendall and Pettitt tests on each CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, pandas

Here is a function that will take each text file in a directory, do the Mann-Kendall and Pettitt tests, and then write the output to a text file. Would you please suggest me improve the code to make it more robust overall?

My attempt is:

```py
## importing required python modules/libraries
import ntpath
import glob
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pymannkendall as mk
import pyhomogeneity as hg

## provide a path location of the input text files
file_path = "C:/Users/Desktop/data/*.txt"

## provide a path location where the output file will be stored
output_path = "C:/Users/Desktop/data/Output/output.txt"

def MK_trend_test():
    for filename in glob.glob(path):
        print (filename)
        df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None)
        result1 = str(mk.original_test(df))
        result2 = str(hg.pettitt_test(df))

        ## to get the only file name NOT the whole path
        only_file = ntpath.basename(filename)

        ## to write and save output in a text file
        with open(output_path,'a') as file:
            file.write(str(only_file) + '\n' + result1 + '\n')
            file.write(result2 + '\n')
            file.write('\n')
```